# How to get values of one column based on another column using specific match values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 5 columns contains [ Voltage,Bus,Load,load_Values,transmission,    transmission_Values]. all the column name with Values contain numerical value based on their corresponding value.The csv files looks like that below

```
Voltage     Bus    Load   load_Values   transmission    transmission_Values
Voltage(1)  2      load(1)   3          transmission(1)      2
Voltage(2)  2      load(2)   4          transmission(2)      3
Voltage(5)  3      load(3)   5          transmission(3)       5
```

I have to fetch value of Bus based on Transmission and load. for example
To get the value of bus. First, I need to fetch the value of transmission(2) which is 3. Now based on this value, I need to get the value of load which is load(3)=5.Next, Based on this value, I have to get the value of Voltage(5) which is 3.

I tried to get the value of single column based on the their corresponding column value.

```
total=df[df['load']=='load(1)']['load_Values']
next_total= df[df['transmission']=='transmission['total']']['transmission_Values']
v_total= df[df['Voltage']=='Voltage(5)']['Voltage_Values']
```

How to get all these values automatically. For example, if i have 1100 values in every column, How I can fetch all the values for 1100 in these columns.

[This is how dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvVq.png) 
So to get the Value of VRES_LD which is new column. For that I have to look for the I__ND_LD Column which has value I__ND_LD(1) and corressponding value stored in I__ND_LD_Values which is 10. Once I get the value 10 now based on that I ahve to Look for I__BS_ND column which has I__BS__ND(10) and its value is 5.0 in I__BS_ND_Values. Based on this value, I have to find the value of V_BS(5) which is 0.986009. Now this value should be store in the new column VRES_LD. Please let me know if you get it now.

Comment: Have a Look at it now! I have changed the name of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generalized your solution so you can work with as many values as you want.

I changed the name "Load_Value" to "load_value_name" to avoid confusion since there is a variable named "load_value" in lowercase.

You can start with as many values as you want; in our example we start with "1":

```
start_values = [1]
load_value_name = [f"^I__ND_LD({n})" for n in start_values]
#Output: but you'll have more than one if needed
['^I__ND_LD(1)']
```

Then we fetch all the values:

```
load_values=df[df['I__ND_LD'].isin(load_names)]['I__ND_LD_Values'].values.astype(np.int)
#output: again, more if needed
array([10])
```

let's get the bus names:

```
bus_names = [f"^I__BS_ND({n})" for n in load_values]
bus_values = df[df['I__BS_ND'].isin(bus_names)]['I__BS_ND_Values'].values.astype(np.int)
#output
array([5])
```

And finally voltage:

```
voltage_bus_value = [f"^V_BS({n})" for n in bus_values]
voltage_values = df[df['V_BS'].isin(voltage_names)]['V_BS_Values'].values
#output
array([0.98974069])
```

Notes:
Instead of rounding I downcasted to int; and .isin() method looks for all occurances so you can fetch all of the values.

Comment: I have a question instead of writing load_names,bus_names,voltage_names what should I write their because it shows error that these are not defined. and to store Voltage_value do i need to define arrays for storing all the value. Secondly If I need to take to scroll all the values of column automatically lets say it will count values of index which is 1100 then automatically do it for 1100 values. Thank you very much Sir

Comment: Well, they are defined. So you either spelt in different ways (note that there is an "s" at the end) or that I just misspelled them on this page. Or if you are using a notebook you need to re-run the cell where you defined the variable.

Comment: Well, to store the value you need to specify the indicies or a range of indices. First define the columns: df["column_for_storage"] = np.nan and than store my_array like this df[:len(my_array),"column_for_storage"]=my_array

Comment: 'df['VRES_LD']=np.nan
df[:len(voltage_values),"VRES_LD"]=voltage_values'  the above error i got "Length of values does not match length of index". Sir , one more question if i need to calculate for 11000 column values how can i do that because everytime start_values=1.

Comment: Yes sorry, you need to use iloc, so substitute this: df[:len(voltage_values),"VRES_LD"]=voltage_values with this: df.iloc[:len(voltage_values),df.columns=="VRES_LD"]=voltage_values

Comment: About your second question, you can set as many start values as you want. start_values = [1,2,3,10,15] for example

Comment: Sir, I have a question, if you free could you please help me out?

Comment: Post your question but I'll hardly have time today

Comment: I have a question. For calculating voltage_values in the array I am not getting the entire list. For calculating all the values I am not getting all the values using this method in array

Comment: Hi Sir, Could you pleas have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304478/pandas-isin-ignoring-duplicate . let me know your comment/suggestion how can I solve that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to create key/value tables and use `merge`. The step to `voltage` is a little unclear, but the basic idea below should work, I think:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'voltage': {0: 'Voltage(1)', 1: 'Voltage(2)', 2: 'Voltage(5)'},
 'bus': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'load': {0: 'load(1)', 1: 'load(2)', 2: 'load(3)'},
 'load_values': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5},
 'transmission': {0: 'transmission(1)',
  1: 'transmission(2)',
  2: 'transmission(3)'},
 'transmission_values': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 5}})

load = df[['load', 'load_values']].copy()
trans = df[['transmission','transmission_values']].copy()
load['load'] = load['load'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(int)
trans['transmission'] = trans['transmission'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(int)

(df[['bus']].merge(trans, how='left', left_on='bus', right_on='transmission')
            .merge(load, how='left', left_on='transmission_values', right_on='load'))
```

resulting in:

```
   bus  transmission  transmission_values  load  load_values
0    2             2                    3   3.0          5.0
1    2             2                    3   3.0          5.0
2    3             3                    5   NaN          NaN
```

Comment: We have some thousands value in every column and every column name is unique with different value and I have to get the particular value of the voltage based on the transmission name and load name with their values. I have issues with to fetch the particular value of column with its name. for example. How I am going to write the condition for  transmission(2) to get the value 3, next time may be I have to fetch the value for transmission(1100) which has some value. Let me know if you understand

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 3 things.

1.You need to put a number inside a string. You do it like this:

```
n_cookies = 3
f"I want {n_cookies} cookies"
#Output
I want 3 cookies
```

2.Let's say the values you need to fetch are:

```
transmission_values = [2,5,20]
You than need to fetch those load values:
load_values_to_fetch = [f"transmission({n})" for n in transmission_values]
#output
[transmission(2),transmission(5),transmission(20)]
```

3.Get all the voltage values from the df. Use .isin() method:

```
voltage_value= df[df['Voltage'].isin(load_values_to_fetch )]['Voltage_Values'].values
```

I hope I understood the problem correctly. Try and let us know because I can't try the code without data

Comment: [This is how dataset looks like ][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvVq.png  So to get the Value of VRES_LD which is new column. For that I have to look for the I__ND_LD Column which has value I__ND_LD(1) and corressponding value stored in I__ND_LD_Values which is 10. Once I get the value 10 now based on that I ahve to Look for I__BS_ND column which has I__BS__ND(10) and its value is 5.0 in I__BS_ND_Values. Based on this value, I have to find the value of V_BS(5) which is 0.986009. these value should be store in the new column VRES_LD. Please let me know if you get it now.

Comment: I think your example is clear. I just don't have the data to try my solution. I'll take a look at your link tomorrow as in my timezone is getting late.

Comment: Sure ! no worries If you want I can send you sample dataset as well

Comment: Sure, send it. Easier that way

Comment: Did you get a chance to have a look

Comment: I can do it now

Comment: Sorry but I don't have permission to access the file

Comment: This is the code I have done to get the first value

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188BHyb4QAI-jIslOQFWu6B2k46XQcWd9YRmalY8zKmg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please open the above link to access the sheet . thank you

Comment: Can you access the above link now ? please let me know

Comment: Yes I see it. There is a lot of stuff and I need to load it on pandas, so it won't be a quick answer

Comment: `df1 = df[['V_BS','V_BS_Values','I__BS_ND','I__BS_ND_Values','I__ND_LD','I__ND_LD_Values']]                                                                                        
Load_Value =f"^I__ND_LD(1)" load_value=round(df[df['I__ND_LD']==Load_Value]['I__ND_LD_Values'].item())
bus_name=f"^I__BS_ND({load_value})"
bus_value =round(df[df['I__BS_ND']==bus_name]['I__BS_ND_Values'].item())
voltage_bus_value = f"^V_BS({bus_value})"
voltage_value=df[df['V_BS']==voltage_bus_value]['V_BS_Values'].item()
voltage_value` This is code I have used for getting the first value of V_BS. Have a look !

Comment: Similarly, I want to get all the value in the different column for example VRES_LD.

Comment: Ok. Loaded and used your code. Works. Now,You want to put 10, 5 and 0.9897 in a new column named VRES_LD? At what index? 0,1,2?

Comment: I generalized your code so you can used it for as many values as you want. I added a new answer since the first one can still have some meaning for other users.

Comment: I just want to put 0.9897 into new column because that is the value i need