# isin() method in pandas ignoring the duplicate values. how can we prevent that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fetching all the values from the dataframes I cant show it here but all the column names that mentioned in the code exist in this dataframe. Since, I am using isin() method to fetch the values from the column. isin() method does not gives you duplicate values but I want the duplicate values as well. In the above code i shows that how I used isin() method to fetch the multiple values from multiple column. In the voltage_values variable i used isin() method which not fetching the duplicate values.What Can i do that does not remove duplicate values.

```py
start_values = [1,2,3]
load_value_name = [f"^I__ND_LD({n})" for n in start_values]
load_values=df[df['I__ND_LD'].isin(load_value_name)]['I__ND_LD_Values'].values.astype(np.int)
print(load_values)
bus_names = [f"^I__BS_ND({n})" for n in load_values]
print(bus_names)
bus_values = df[df['I__BS_ND'].isin(bus_names)]['I__BS_ND_Values'].values.astype(np.int)
print(bus_values)
voltage_bus_value = [f"^VMEAS_BS({n})" for n in bus_values]
print(voltage_bus_value)
voltage_values = df[df['VMEAS_BS'].isin(voltage_bus_value)]['VMEAS_BS_Values'].reindex().values
print(voltage_values)
```

The above shows the corresponding output

```
load_values=[10 45 44]
bus_names=['^I__BS_ND(10)', '^I__BS_ND(45)', '^I__BS_ND(44)']
bus_values=[ 5 17 17]
voltage_bus_value=['^VMEAS_BS(5)', '^VMEAS_BS(17)', '^VMEAS_BS(17)']
voltage_values=[0.9908185  0.99612296]
```

As we can see that "^VMEAS_BS(17)" came two times but in the array I got only only one value which is 0.99612296 but I want this value two times. What could be the possible solution for that.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: hmmm, my problem is I have no your data, so cannot test your solution.

Comment: Hi, anmol. I'm checking right now. I don't see why you shouldn't get all values, duplicated included. Do you have a new df or is it the same as last time?

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand where the problem is. Yes, isin() doesn't work. Let me think of a solution...

Comment: its same as we discussed last time.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have VMEAS_BS in my dataframe, so I'll show you the result with load_values.

This is the quickest I can think of:

Substitute

```
voltage_values = df[df['VMEAS_BS'].isin(voltage_bus_value)]['VMEAS_BS_Values'].reindex().values
```

with all these lines (sorry!!)

```
voltage_values = []
for _,value in enumerate(voltage_values):
  voltage_values.extend(df[df['VMEAS_BS'] == value]['VMEAS_BS_Values'].reindex().values)
```

Here is an example with load_values

```
load_values = []
for _,value in enumerate(load_value_name):
  load_values.extend(df[df['I__ND_LD']== value]['I__ND_LD_Values'].values.astype(np.int))
#output
[10, 45, 44]
```

Comment: You need to do a loop because you can't select one line twice, of course. So if you want it twice, you need to call it twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045169/how-to-get-values-of-one-column-based-on-another-column-using-specific-match-val/57052940#57052940 This is same problem you solved it the only issues is with duplicate values with isin() method

Comment: can we move to a chat room?

Comment: I'm not sure, first time. Try this link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/197331/anmol-chat-room?tab=general

Comment: I can't chat because i have 14 reputation it should be atleast 20

Comment: Noop, Not available. Do you use skype? I have only 13 reputations as per comment. required at least 20. 7 more required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197335/discussion-between-anmol-and-francesco-zambolin).